# Horizontal scrolling of uicollectionview with fixed header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Attempting to create a custom collection view layout that enables sticky/fixed header while the collection view scrolls horizontally. The cells will sit below the header while paging is enabled.

Vertically, I can call `layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true` along side setting the headerReference size which will pin the header to the top. Nevertheless, horziontally the header jumps and sits to the left of the window rather sitting at the top.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Same here, looking to achieve that in one of my current project.

Comment: @EdouardBarbier I haven't achieved it myself just yet but I was informed that it's a page view controller that has a UIView at that top which acts as a sticky header. It also makes use of a generic interface somewhere to help synchronise the scrolling between the controllers.  I will probably attempt it in a couple weeks time when I get the chance. If you do give it a go, let me know how you get on.

Comment: @hablema read above